# isEnable() is not working in selenium webdriver for find the button is enabled or disabled?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i am trying the bellow code,but always return true value.

```
                if(updatebuton_status=="true"){

                Thread.sleep(timmer*3);
                //click on the update button                
                //ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).click();
                ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/span/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).click();      

                }else{
                Thread.sleep(timmer*3);
                //click on the Add button               
                ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/span/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).click();
                 }
```

[image]

Comment: Where `isEnable()` (`isEnabled()` actually) used in your code? I don't see any lines with it. Do you want us to guess how your `updatebuton_status` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere you are doing wrong as your `xpath` is too long recommended to use `relative xpath`. and if your element having `id` then use it directly

I don't know how you are checking that element is displayed
use following method to do same -

```
boolean check= driver.findElement(By.id("tVLQur-btn")).isEnabled(); 

if(check)    // if `check` returns true then go in if condition
{
     driver.findElement(By.id("tVLQur-btn")).click();
}
else
{
     // DO SOME OTHER FUNCTIONALITY
}
```

**Edited**

If your button id is dynamic then use following `xpath` to find the element

```
//td[contains(.,'Update')]/../preceding-sibling::tr//button
```

like

```
boolean check= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(.,'Update')]/../preceding-sibling::tr//button")).isEnabled();
```

It will find your update button and check weather it is enable or not

Comment: Sorry the line has been missed,below code i am using.  boolean updatebuton_status=ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).isEnabled();
                                                             
     But the id are not static,so i am using xpth.

Comment: r you not able to get the update button using `id` ?

Comment: no. the id's and name are dynamic, so i couldn't  use that, so i am using entire xpath.

Comment: OK, then make xpath more specific don't use absolute xpath atleast

Answer (score 0):

I believe at the very least if you break the line into two statements, one to located the element, and the next to check its enabled status, at least you'll know that the problem (most likely) lies in the element location, as it would return a nul to the web element and isEnabled would return a null pointer exception.  There are always ways to use relatively short xpaths if no consistent ID is available.  Check your browser for add-ins that include the word xpath, and you'll see there are a variety of xpath helpers out there.  The inspect element option is the safest, at least in theory, but it's not always the best.